# Update Jpanel displayed content from long event

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I have a JPanel with a lot of JLabels, each with action listener.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                                Method1();
                                Method2();
                                  }
```

Both methods update the conetent of some of the JLabels, but the update is shown only after Method2 finishes (which takes a few seconds). Is there a way to refresh the graphics after Method1 finishes? I have tried  repaint(); and                            revalidate(); with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have two options (There will be more, for sure):

First:

```
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

Second: (I don´t recommend it so much)

```
label.paintImmediately(x, y, width, height); //for every label
```

Comment: It´s the one i use too, but you need to be carefull not to change parameters (x, y, width and height) (That´s  why i said i don´t recommend it, but if it works fine, just go on). :)